# Как я могу увидеть причину отклонения по каждой правке?

Tags: обсуждение

Ряд моих правок отклонён.

В статье "Как пользоваться очередью «Предлагаемые правки»?" сказано "Отклоняя правку, необходимо указать причину."

В статье "Как работают предложенные правки?" сказано:"Вы можете просматривать список всех правок, когда-либо предложенных вами, в своей учетной записи, нажав на кнопку «все действия», расположенную во вкладке «Активность». Далее перейдите на страницу «предложения». Каждая строка списка включает в себя ссылку на предложенную правку, по которой можно перейти на нее, а также ссылку на редактируемое сообщение."

Но я не вижу страницу "предложения". Есть страница "предложенные правки", там только ссылки на сами вопросы, и там видно, что отклонили, но причину (и саму правку) я не вижу, даже переходя на вопрос, где правку делал.

Как я могу увидеть причину отклонения по каждой правке?

Comment: Хм.. Странно, вроде раньше было... Может что-то поломали при смене ui?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, даже не знаю, что мне делать дальше, если это ответ модератора:-) Я сам ничего старался не ломать. Если не трудно, может, сами взглянете на отказы мои, да как-то в комментарий выложите - там 5 штук?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, закрыт вопрос, отзываю мою просьбу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё на месте: [отправляетесь в активность > предложенные правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/489515/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) и нажимайте на «принять / отклонить» (грамматически, конечно, должно быть «принята / отклонена», но это уже другой вопрос…)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё понятно. Да, работает всё так. Не ясно было из описания в статье "Как работают предложенные правки?", что надо на эти слова нажимать.